# Implementing font-size: 62.5% in Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am currently trying to set the root font-size to 62.5% to make REM calculations easier at 10px. I am then setting the body font-size to 1.6rem. Currently, this works but affects bootstraps REM sizing as it picks up the font-size of 10px instead of 16px in the body.

I am doing this reset in a stylesheet called shared.sass and have a seperate sass file called custom.sass that includes all of the bootstrap 5 components, functions and so on. I am then loading the custom.css first in the HTML document followed by the custom.css followed by the HTML's stylesheet itself.

I am wondering if there is a way to set the base font-size to 62.5% without affecting all of the bootstrap components and sizing classes.

Comment: Personally I've set $font-size-root: 62.5%; and $font-size-base: 1.6rem; and I recalculated all the values (value/0.625), I really don't know how to automate that either, someone will maybe answer a way to.